# DialogFragment doesn't pan with SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialogfragment which has some content in it including an EditText field. 
Unfortunately when I click on the EditText field, the softkeyboard covers the dismiss button for the dialog. This is a problem which I resolved by using

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the dialog shrinks and other items in it get covered. I tried using `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` instead, but only the containing activity adjusted in that case, the dialogfragment itself didn't move and the dismiss buttons are still covered. Is there any way I can make just the dialogfragment pan?

My relevant dialogfragment code looks like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        mContactSupportView.findViewById(R.id.compose_message).clearFocus();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the code in on onresume instead, I find it more reliable, and then turn it off in onPause if that's what you want.

Comment: Any luck with the problem solution?

Comment: any luck with the solution? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Used

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

in the DialogFragment's `onCreateView` but the only thing that was panning was the activity behind it.

The problem was that I was setting the dialog's height to `MATCH_PARENT`. After changing the height to an exact value, the DialogFragment panned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog layout attr. should be match_parent. When open keyboard open then strech your dialog layout. Such as samsung galaxy "create new folder" dialog.